# Evaluated Two Futures with Separate Completion Times

Tags: scala, future

Given the following 2 methods of type `Future[Int]`:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent._

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> def g: Future[Int] = Future { Thread.sleep(5000); 100 }
g: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]

scala> def f: Future[Int] = Future { Thread.sleep(50000); 100 }
f: scala.concurrent.Future[Int]
```

I'd like to return a `Future[Boolean]` if either future value is greater than 0.

Notice that one Future completes in 50 seconds, whereas the other finishes in 5 seconds.

```
scala> def foo: Future[Boolean] = for {
     |   x <- f
     |   y <- g
     | } yield ( (x > 0) || (y > 0) )
foo: scala.concurrent.Future[Boolean]

scala> Await.result(foo, 20 second)
warning: there were 1 feature warning(s); re-run with -feature for details
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [20 seconds]
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219)
```

When I run it, I observe a Timeout due to, I assume, the 50 second future.

Is it possible to re-write `foo` to return `true` as soon as either future finishes?

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used them, but there are some good candidates amongst the [`Future` object methods](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$):

`Future.firstCompletedOf` Returns a new Future to the result of the first future in the list that is completed.

`Future.reduce` Initiates a fold over the supplied futures where the fold-zero is the result value of the Future that's completed first.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Future.firstCompletedOf` if your futures return distinct results. Your examples both return the same int, but you could always `map` them to give them an some distinct identify, in this case an `Either`, like this:

```
val f1: Either[Int,Int] = f().map(Left(_))
val g1: Either[Int,Int] = g().map(Right(_))
val futureOfFirst = Future.firstCompledOf(Seq(f1,g1)).map {
  case Left(x) => x
  case Right(x) => x
}
val first = Await.result(futureOfFirst, 20 seconds)
println(s"first result: $first")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Short Answer

Use the following code

```
  val firstPositiveNumber = Future.find(Seq(g, f))(_ > 0)
  val maybeResult = Await.result(firstPositiveNumber, 3 seconds)
  println(maybeResult.isDefined)
```

## Detailed Answer

### [`find`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$) utility

The easiest way to achieve this requirement, which is a common use case, is to use the [`find`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$) utility from `Future` companion object.

Assuming that you have two futures defined like this

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  val g = Future {
    Thread.sleep(4000)
    100
  }

  val f = Future {
    Thread.sleep(2000)
    -100
  }
```

you can use `find`

```
val firstPositiveNumber = Future.find(Seq(g, f))(it => it > 0)
```

to create a future that completes when at least one of the provided futures completes successfully with the result passing the provided condition. In case of all the futures failed the result will be `Failure`.

Note that the type of the resulting future is `Future[Option[Int]]` which makes sense because some the futures might succeed with none of their results satisfying the condition. In that case the result will be `None` (of course wrapped in a `Success` as the future itself is successful).

### Type of the future

If you insist on returning `Future[Boolean]` and not `Future[Option[Int]]`, which makes sense in this case (as the result is always either `false` or `true`), you can easily use `map`:

```
val anyPositive = firstPositiveNumber map (_.isDefined)
val result = Await.result(anyPositive, 3.seconds)
println(result)
```

### Scala API

You can read more about all the utilities in `Future` (combining futures, filtering them, etc.) in the [Scala API](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/#scala.concurrent.Future$)